# How to create async dynamic components in Vue

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, vue.js, components, vue-component

I understand [dynamic](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html) components, I understand [async](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html) components, but I have no clue how to combine the two (rhyme unintended).

How can I rewrite

```
<template>
    <component :is="name" v-if="component" />
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'dynamic-async-loader',

  props: ['name'],

  components: {
    compA: () => import('./components/compA'),
    compB: () => import('./components/compB'),
    compC: () => import('./components/compC'),
  },
};
</script>
```

to be able to omit the components object and instead pass the path as a prop? e.g.

```
<template>
    <component :is="name" v-if="component" />
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'dynamic-async-loader',

  props: ['name', 'path'],

  // magic
};
</script>
```

So I'll be able to do the following

```
<dynamic-async-loader :name="'compA'" :path="'./components/compA'" />
<dynamic-async-loader :name="'compB'" :path="'./components/compB'" />
<dynamic-async-loader :name="'compC'" :path="'./components/compC'" />
```

Can someone explain me the magic?